# How can heat be a inexact differntial, in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics

I came across this definition of the first law of thermodynamics in [Differential Forms of Fundamental Equations](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Thermodynamics/Energies_and_Potentials/Differential_Forms_of_Fundamental_Equations):

$$dU={\bar d}q+{\bar d}w,$$

where it states that the symbol $\bar{d}$ is an inexact differential. But I don't understand how heat is an inexact differential.

I mean work is because, work is dependent on its path, so it has a path function, but I never come across a path function for heat. Is there a path function for heat?

Comment: Can the difference between an exact differential ($dU$) and an inexact differential ($dW$) ever be an exact differential?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of heat supplied during a given change of thermodynamic state depends on the path of the change.

For example, consider an ideal gas moving from $(p_1,V_1)$ to $(p_2,V_2)$. There are an infinite number of routes it could follow. Let's consider two:

$$
\mbox{either }\; (p_1,V_1) \rightarrow (p_2,V_1) \rightarrow (p_2,V_2)\\
\mbox{or }\;\;\;\;\;\; (p_1,V_1) \rightarrow (p_1,V_2) \rightarrow (p_2,V_2)
$$
where the change indicated by each arrow falls on a straight line on a $p,V$ diagram.
The internal energy $U$ changes by the same amount for these two routes, since $U$ is a function of state. But the work done in these two routes is different: in the first case it is $p_2(V_1-V_2)$ but in the second case it is $p_1 (V_1-V_2)$. It follows that the heat supplied differs also.

Now let's look a little more generally. For the case of irreversible heat transfer one can write
$$
\bar{d}Q_{\rm rev} = T\,dS
$$
where $T$ and $S$ are functions of state. But there is no single-valued function whose differential is $T\,dS$. Proof: suppose that there were such a function and call it $f$. Then we have
$$
df = T\,dS \\
\Rightarrow \;\;
\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial S}\right|_T = T, \;\;
\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial T}\right|_S = 0 \\
\Rightarrow \;\;
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial T\,\partial S} = 1, \;\;
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial S\,\partial T} = 0.
$$
Hence 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial T\,\partial S}
\ne \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial S\,\partial T} 
$$
But this is impossible for a well-behaved single-valued function. Hence we have that $T\,dS$ is not a proper differential. QED

Comment: Can we say $\int \bar{d}Q_{\rm rev} = \int T\,dS$ ?

Comment: @adosar yes, and the value of the integral will depend on the path along which it is integrated

Comment: @If we write $\int \bar{d}Q = Q$ this doesn't mean that there is a function Q because the differential of heat is inexact? So what we mean by integration of $\bar{d}q$ is just the total heat Q?

Comment: @adosar it is a function, but not a function of state. Its value cannot be written as the difference of two unique values at either end of the path. Compare it to the question, 'how long is the journey from London to Bristol?' The question is well-defined, and it has an answer, but the answer depends on the route chosen for the journey.

Comment: So $\int \bar{d}q$ means just the total heat?

Comment: @adosar yes. Please note, I may not be able to devote further time to this.

Comment: Thank you so much.